# ¿@foreach en laravel que vaya de 2 objetos en 2 objetos?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, foreach

Estoy construyendo un blog en laravel pero me encontre con un problema en mi plantilla del blog, desde el archivo de rutas mando por compact la variable post:

```
Route::get('/blog', function () {
    $posts = App\Post::latest('published_at')->get();
    return view('blog', compact('posts'));
});
```

y desde la vista implemento un `@foreach`:

```
<!-- Blog -->
<div class="section blog-posts" id="blog-section">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-m-12 col-t-6 col-d-6">
            <div class="blog_item animated">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="blog-page.html"><img src="mcard/images/blog/blog1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="i_title">
                        <div class="icon"><strong>{{ $post->published_at->format('d') }}</strong> {{ $post->published_at->format('M') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category_bts">
                        @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
                        <a href="#" class="category">#{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="name">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                    <p>
                        {{ $post->excerpt }}
                    </p>
                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="btn btn_animated"><span class="circle">Leer más</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-m-12 col-t-6 col-d-6">
            <div class="blog_item animated">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="blog-page.html"><img src="mcard/images/blog/blog1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="i_title">
                        <div class="icon"><strong>{{ $post->published_at->format('d') }}</strong> {{ $post->published_at->format('M') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category_bts">
                        @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
                        <a href="#" class="category">#{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="name">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                    <p>
                        {{ $post->excerpt }}
                    </p>
                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="btn btn_animated"><span class="circle">Leer más</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
```

El problema es que por cada fila (row) deberian haber 2 post y si coloco el foreach donde lo estoy colocando por cada fila me repetiria 2 veces el mismo post.

Comment: tengo duda ¿por qué debería mostrarte 2? trata de ser mas claro por favor

Comment: Debe mostrarme 2 porque asi es la plantilla que adquiri, osea quisiera dejar la plantilla como esta y no modificarla. En el siguiente link se puede ver con mas claridad [Web del Blog](https://jesushenriquez.com/blog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se soluciona de la siguiente manera:

```
 @foreach($posts->chunk(2) as $post)
<div class="row">
    @foreach($post as $postf)
    <div class="col col-m-12 col-t-6 col-d-6">
        <div class="blog_item animated">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="blog-page.html"><img src="mcard/images/blog/blog1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content-box">
                <div class="i_title">
                    <div class="icon"><strong>{{ $postf->published_at->format('d') }}</strong> {{ $postf->published_at->format('M') }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="category_bts">
                        @foreach($postf->tags as $tag)
                            <a href="#" class="category">#{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="name">{{ $postf->title }}</a>
                    <p>
                        {{ $postf->excerpt }}
                    </p>
                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="btn btn_animated"><span class="circle">Leer más</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

Es decir el segmento

> @foreach($posts->chunk(2) as $post)

Lo que hace es hacerle un split al arreglo $posts y colocarlo de 2 en 2 en otro arreglo llamado $post, es por eso que luego se debe colocar este otro segmento

> @foreach($post as $postf)

En donde ese arreglo que va de 2 en 2 lo recorreremos de 1 en 1 para que se adapte a la plantilla.

Comment: El inconveniente es en el primer @foreach($posts as $post) ya que los posts son los que no se como mostrarlos ya que por cada row van 2 posts como se ve en el siguiente enlace [web blog](https://jesushenriquez.com/blog)

Comment: Adicional a eso son 2 post por fila pero la idea es que si hay 10 post se muestren de 2 en 2

Comment: Ya te entendi, ya lo edite

Comment: Funciono para los dos primeros post, pero si tiene mas de 2 post se daña. Estoy buscando la estructura del metodo chunk en laravel para ver como podria solucionar esto, ya que hay dos problemas el primero es que no acepta mas de 2 post porque se daña y el segundo que cuando es un numero impar se podria dañar tambien

Comment: Listo ya funciono, tenia que colocar doble foreach, utilizar el method chunk para splitear el primer arreglo pero al splitearlo este crea un segundo arreglo de tamaño 2 entonces hago el segundo foreach y lo asigno a otra variable y listo

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó. Si es posible sugiere una edición a mi respuesta con algo más parecido a lo que hiciste

Comment: Listo ya edite tu respuesta con lo que se hizo

Answer (score 0):

¿Y por qué no simplemente iteras adentro de row imprimiendo columnas?, cuando las columnas sobrepasan el límite de 12 unidades deberían de  imprimirse abajo dando la alusión a que es otra fila visualmente, si te llegan a quedar espacios vacíos y las columnas no se llenan adecuadamente, ya sería problema de tus estilos. Para lo que estás haciendo tus posts deberían de tener la misma altura y si no la tienen sería, a mi parecer, mal diseño de interfaz.

Tu código debería de quedar así:

```
<!-- Blog -->
                <div class="section blog-posts" id="blog-section"> 
                    <div class="row">
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <div class="col col-m-12 col-t-6 col-d-6">
                            <div class="blog_item animated">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="blog-page.html"><img src="mcard/images/blog/blog1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="content-box">
                                    <div class="i_title">
                                        <div class="icon"><strong>{{ $post->published_at->format('d') }}</strong> {{ $post->published_at->format('M') }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="category_bts">
                                        @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
                                        <a href="#" class="category">#{{ $tag->name }}</a>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="name">{{ $post->title }}</a>
                                    <p>
                                        {{ $post->excerpt }}
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="blog-page.html" class="btn btn_animated"><span class="circle">Leer más</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: No se puede porque es necesario que cada 2 post se cree un "row" para que el diseño del template se conserve y se vea bien, si hago lo que sugieres quedarian todos los post pegados sin espacio de separación entre los de arriba y abajo

Comment: @JesúsHenríquez De hecho, deberías de checar lo que te hace cada clase de bootstrap en CSS y si dices que se ven pegados es porque el row te da un margen, margen que tú podrías ponerle a cada una de las columnas manualmente y conservar el diseño, no te encierres sólo con lo que te da bootstrap, también ponle de tu parte.

Comment: Lo se, pero el template fue diseñado por encargados del frontend y no es permitido modificarlo, de igualforma ya solucione el inconveniente.